# Find the value of $x$, given $y$.

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, statistics

Suppose $y$ and $x$ are related by the expression $$y = a + bx,\quad a\in \mathbf R, b \gt 0.$$ 
Given the value of say $y$ and knowing the ratio $\frac{a}{b}$, is it possible to find(or perhaps estimate) $x$ without knowing the value of $b$? Obviously, one can find $x$ in terms of $b$, but I'm not interested in that. Is it at all possible?

Answer (score 2):

Well, solving for $x$ using usual algebra, we end up with

$$x=\frac{y-a}b=\frac yb-\frac ab$$

We know what $\frac ab$ is, but we don't know what $\frac yb$ is, thus, without knowing more information, we cannot deduce what $x$ is.  For example, if $y=0$, then we know what $x$ is.  We can't even approximate.  For example, suppose $\frac ab=1$.  Then,

$$a=b=1\implies x=y-1$$

$$a=b=1000\implies x=\frac y{1000}-1$$

These two possible scenarios differ drastically, so we can't even make estimates.

Comment: what if we know that $\frac{y}{b}$ lies withing some interval, say, $[a,\frac{a}{b}]$?

Comment: Then that is the approximation:$$x\in[a-1,\frac ab-1]$$@Gorg

Answer (score 0):

From $y = a + bx$ we get $x=\frac{y}{b}-\frac{a}{b}$. Now suppose we know $\frac{a}{b}=1$, then

$x=\frac{y}{b}-1$.

If $y=1$ , then $x=\frac{1}{b}-1$.

And nothing can be said about $x$ if $b$ is un-known.